# React Native ios not showing local image

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, deployment

## Environment

- macOS : 10.14.6
- Xcode : 11.0
- react : 16.8.6
- react-native : 0.60.5
- project folder structure : [google drive image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nvB_O5LH2p-vq9qyR-V7cPmmWVS5lars)

## Background

I made a simple app. I tested it on Android/iOS simulator and real device.
It worked well all. Now I'm trying to deploy on App Store.

## Problem

I changed the build scheme on Xcode from debug to release ( product -> scheme -> edit scheme -> run -> build configuration ).
And I run it on simulator. And result was [this(google drive image link)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ah8zmTMR4tucntKbcA43mwjcOmlG07fI).

I don't know why my app cannot load static image.
If I changed the scheme to debug it shows well like [this(google drive image link)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jL5fp_gfHdrBkVkCAJ0r9xNmO3xSP_Rz).

## Maybe...?

1. I got this error `/Users/mac88/Desktop/Projects/팀포크봇/VoiceCarRN/ios/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory` after I remove main.jsbundle file in ios folder.
2. `2019-10-13 02:09:06.046867+0900 VoiceCarRN[44601:3301900] [PERF ASSETS] Loading image at size {854, 1334}, which is larger than the screen size {750, 1334}`

Check please !

Answer (score 2):

After you create the jsbundle and assets folder using this command

`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

you will have to include both of them in `Copy Bundle Resources` step in `Build Phases`, since you are running the app in release configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Is this process required everytime I make a react-native app for ios ? 
Or did I something wrong in react-native configuration ?

Comment: This is required every time you build your app in release configuration, from xCode.

Answer (score 1):

use this commmad in inside project to copy assert from app to ios folder

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

please install react-native cli for running above command.

for this warning

```
Loading image at size {854, 1334}, which is larger than the screen size {750, 1334}
```

just add resizeMode: 'contain' in image style

Answer (score 1):

The real cause was index **.tsx** file.

I'm using typescript, and I used index.tsx.

I changed index.tsx to index **.js** and the image shows up correctly !

Comment: Thanks so much~ I've spent ages and tried numerous way getting this work

Answer (score 1):

add/modify this command in your package.json file

```
“build:ios”: “react-native bundle --entry-file=‘index.js’ --bundle-output=‘./ios/main.jsbundle’ --assets-dest ./ios/release --dev=false --platform=‘ios’”
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue of your xcode version. So try to update xcode 11.7 and don't use Beta version to build React Native. I have same issue with you because I use Xcode 12
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652406