# React Native iOS build succeed but images and logo is not showing

Tags: react-native

I am making an app with React Native and I succeeded in react native iOS build.
So I built an IPA successfully.

Then when I build on my iPhone (development), all images were showed well, but after I build IPA and upload it to the testflight, when I install it on my iPhone, it doesn't display all images(assets).

I implemented this command to link all assets to the project.

> react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

But it doesn't show all images in the assets which is in project. (e.g: project/src/assets/images/book.png)

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949851/react-native-ios-not-showing-images-pods-issue