# Image cannot show image in iOS 14 React Native

Tags: react-native, image, ios14

Getting an issue local images not loading  just showing blank in Ios

```
<Image source={ImagePath.headerBgImage} style={{ width: "100%" }} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I understand correctly, _currentFrame should be for animated image,
> so if it is still image, we can use the UIImage implementation to
> handle image rendering

react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
OR in pods React- RCTImage>RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

Lines 283 to 289 in 1c634a9

```
 - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer 
 { 
   if (_currentFrame) { 
     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale; 
     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage; 
   } 
 }
```

> Replace above code with

```
if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go to this file :

> node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Images > RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

and search word `if (_currentFrame)` then after find that add `else` like this :

```
 if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```

for more info see this [link](http://%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949851/react-native-ios-not-showing-images-pods-issue)