# Local Images (as assets) not Loading in iOS; Expo EAS Build (React Native)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have used several icons in the application, but they are not loading in iOS build, but load perfectly fine in Android build. The icons been used are PNG files in local assets folder. I have tried to use different methods to include Image files;

1. `var chevron_right = require('./chevron-right.png');`
2. `import chevron_right from './chevron-right.png';`
3. Third that I used was to put a JS file (i.e. Icons.js) in the folder where there the images are and than export those images from it. Like: `export default { chevron_right : require('./chevron-right.png') }` and then import where I want Like: `import Icons from './path/to/icons' <Image source={Icons.chevron_right} style={{ height: 8, width: 8 }} />`

All of the above three methods do not work for iOS builds. The screenshots are attached, the versions of expo and react native are:
Expo CLI: 0.60,
Expo SDK: 46,
React: 18,
React Native: 0.69.4

**Screenshots**:

[image: iOS Screenshot]

[image: Android Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my EAS CLI from 0.60 to 1.1.1, now my Images are rendering in iOS build.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with the Xcode. So pls Follow this
[React-native iOS not showing images (pods issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949851/react-native-ios-not-showing-images-pods-issue). Read the full thread.

The question is answered.(Regards)

Comment: But, the thing is I am not using XCode, I am using Expo for creating builds for the app (both Android & iOS).

Comment: Even in Expo , Expo uses xcode

Comment: My Problem is now fixed, I updated my Expo CLI, and EAS CLI, now the images are rendering. It automatically added the code you referred to GitHub Issue. Thank you.